# Magento 2.1 Redirect through htaccess

Tags: magento-2.1, url-rewrite, htaccess

I am unable to 301 redirect URL like

> **`baseurl/blog/international%20enviroguard%20re-branding%20-%20faqs/`** to **`baseurl/blog/international-enviroguard-re-branding-faqs`** through htaccess.

The page is going to 404 redirect.

I am using the below line to redirect in htaccess -

> Redirect 301 /blog/international%20enviroguard%20re-branding%20-%20faqs/ /blog/international-enviroguard-re-branding-faqs

Please provide a solution.

Comment: is that apache server?

Comment: yes it is apache server

Comment: Why you are using htaccess for this ? You can use To create a 301, 302 redirect, open the «Marketing» tab and select the «URL Rewrites» button.

Answer (score 0):

**Magento 2 Redirect (301, 302)**

To implement 301 or 302 redirects in your Magento 2 store:

1. a certain product or category in no longer available in your store;
2. any kind of URLs changes;
3. if you moved to a new website from an old one.

> To create a 301, 302 redirect, open the «Marketing» tab and select the
>   «URL Rewrites» button.

[image]

> Then hit the «Add URL Rewrite» button. Let’s quickly look through the
>   available options:

- Store – select the Store View for which the redirect will be enabled
- Request Path – enter the URL to redirect
- Target Path – enter the URL to which the page will be redirected
- Redirect Type – select the redirect type between 302 (temporary) and
  301 (permanent)
- Description – enter optional description

[image]

> After specifying all the details, hit the «Save» button.

[image]

Now the customers and search engines will be redirected to the correct page and never encounter with a «404 Page Not Found» error in your Magento 2 store.

For more [reference](https://www.mageworx.com/wiki/magento-2-redirect/)

Comment: I tried this first by creating url rewrite as -
Requested path - blog/international%20enviroguard%20re-branding%20-%20faqs/ 
and target path - https://example.com/blog/international-enviroguard-re-branding-faqs
But still not working.

Comment: Which values did you set for Redirect Type ?

Comment: Redirect type - Permanent 301

Comment: It should work please flush the cache and still it doesn't work then, you can use caching headers to do the same thing.

Comment: I reindexed and flushed cache also but still it is directing to 404 page. Please provide a solution.

Comment: well if above all things doesn't work then you can use header

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92721/discussion-between-aaditya-and-chanchal).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by creating a new RewriteRule in htacces as - 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/blog/international\ enviroguard\ re-branding\ -\ faqs/"
RewriteRule .* https://example.com/blog/international-enviroguard-re-branding-faqs [R=301,L]